# How to calculate the volume of an ellipsoid with triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having some troubles since this morning on an exercise.
I need to find the volume of the ellipsoid defined by $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{a^2} + \frac{z^2}{a^2}  \leq 1$.
So at the beginning I wrote
$\left\{\begin{matrix} -a\leq x\leq a 
\\ -b\leq y\leq b
\\ -c\leq z\leq c
\end{matrix}\right.$

Then I wrote this as integral : $\int_{-c}^{c}\int_{-b}^{b}\int_{-a}^{a}1 dxdydz $.

I found as a result : $8abc$

But I knew it was incorrect. I browsed this website and many others for 2 hours and yeah I found that we need to express b and c in terms of x. But I don't know why.. Is there an intuitive way to understand that ? I have already done some double integral with b expressed in terms of a but I never figured out why..

Comment: The answer $8abc$ is the volume of a rectangular prism with sides $2a, 2b, 2c$. Look closer at your integral. It can be easily interpreted as the volume as a rectangular prism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sticking with cartesian coordinates, then you will consider the points inside of the ellipsoid. The limits you wrote in your OP consider all points within $\pm a$,$\pm b$,$\pm c$ as @u8y7451 mentioned.

First, let's find our range of z.

$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} \le 1$

$\frac{z^2}{c^2} \le 1- \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} $

$-c\sqrt{(1- \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2})} \le z \le c\sqrt{(1- \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2})}$

Next, we look at the projection of the ellipsoid onto the x-y plane.

$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \le 1$

This gives our value of y as a function of x.

$\frac{y^2}{b^2} \le 1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2}$

$-b\sqrt{(1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2})} \le y \le b\sqrt{(1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2})}$

$-a \le x \le a$

This should give you the proper ranges for your integrals as:

$\int\limits_{-a}^{a} \int_{-b\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2}}^{b\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2}}\int_{-c\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2 -y^2/b^2}}^{c\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2 -y^2/b^2}}1 dzdydx$

Apologies for the ugliness of that final formula.

---

EDIT: some further explanation.

Suppose you would like to calculate the area inside of an ellipse centered at the origin, with vertices at $(\pm a,0)$ and $(0,\pm b)$ (see image). To do so, you need to decide what values of $(x,y)$ are inside. Clearly, the limits along the $x$-axis are $[-a,+a]$. So you could start at $x=-a$ and move to the right. Now, at each $x$, what values of $y$ are inside the ellipse? From the formula for an ellipse:

$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \le 1 \implies $

$-b\sqrt{(1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2})} \le y \le b\sqrt{(1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2})}$

Now, we could stop here, and calculate the area with a single integral:

$2b\int\limits_{-a}^{a}\sqrt{(1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2})}dx$. [eqn 1]

Effectively we are integrating the height of the ellipse by the width $dx$ (see Fig 1A). This is what most students are more familiar with.

[image: integrating ellipse]

Alternatively, we can go one more step, and instead of integrating columns, we integrate over tiny areas of width $dx$ and height $dy$, centered around each point within the ellipse (this is a little hand-wavy but hopefully Fig 1B makes it clearer). So as before, we start at $x=-a$ moving to the right, and for each x we start at the lower limit of $y$ moving up.

$\int\limits_{-a}^{a} \int_{-b\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2}}^{b\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2}}dydx$ [eqn 2]

[image: integrating ellipse]

The original problem just takes this one step further into the z-dimension.. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this problem is to scale the axes by $a$, $b$, and $c$. That turns the ellipse into a sphere of radius $1$ and multiplies the volume by $1/abc$. So the volume of the ellipsoid is $abc$ times the volume of the unit sphere.

Of course that method doesn't give you any practice with triple integrals.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a modified spherical coordinate to describe the surface (not the interior) as
\begin{align}
x &=a \cos(v)\sin(u) \\
y &=b \sin(v)\sin(u) \\
z &=c \cos(u)
\end{align}
$0 \leq v < 2\pi$ and $0 \leq u \leq \pi$.

Then use the vector field $F=(0,0,z)$ and compute the outer flux through the surface. Note that the divergence of $F$ is $1$ hence by Divergence(Gauss) theorem it will be equal to the volume. But, surface integral is pretty easy.